# Numeric keyboard with negative (-) and dot (.)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have checked all iOS's keyboards and I can't find out, that meets my needs except for `UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation`, but that is not what I am looking for.

I am looking for a keyboard like `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad` or `UIKeyboardTypePhonePad`, where I can add `.` and `-`, but is it possible to create such one?

Answer (score 2):

You should create an `inputAccessoryView`, commonly an UIToolbar with your missing keys (`.` and `-`)